# Proper way to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProcol when using an unmanaged executable

Tags: c#, .net, com, unmanaged, managed

I have an unmanaged (C++) program that uses multiple managed (C#) DLLs via COM and I need those DLLs to use TLS1.2. All the DLLs target .NET 4.6 or higher,  but that doesn't seem to matter.

When I run managed programs that target .NET 4.6 and 4.7 and call a managed DLL, the SecurityProtocol is set to `Tls, Tls11, Tls12` and`SystemDefault`, respectively, and TLS1.2 is used. When I run my unmanaged program and call the same managed DLL, the SecurityProtocol is set to `Ssl3, Tls` and it does not use TLS1.2.

### What doesn't work:

- Setting the `supportedRuntime` in MyProgram.exe.config. Adding `<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" /></startup>` to the config file had no effect on the SecurityProtocol.

### What works, but is not optimal:

- Creating a new DLL that explicitly sets the SecurityProtocol and calling it in the unmanaged program before anything else; the SecurityProtocol will then be correctly set for calls to all other DLLs. This works well but I don't want to add another dependency to my project just for this.
- Setting `AppContextSwitchOverrides` in the config file by adding the line `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto=false" />` will cause the SecurityProtocol to be `Tls, Tls11, Tls12`. This works well, but seems like a hack that exploits undocumented (and possibly unintended) behavior.

Is there any better way to get the managed DLLs' SecurityProtocol to use either `Tls12` or `SystemDefault` when running my unmanaged program? Thanks.

Comment: DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto is all but a hack and is documented, for example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls. However things have changed since .NET 4.7 (by default .NET uses the OS's default) so take the time to read the chapter about 4.7. It depends on what classes you use. If you use SslStream, you can use new method overloads that take an SslProtocols parameter (this is not recommended) and force Tls12 from .NET code directly

Comment: @SimonMourier I wish I had found that document earlier. I had only found references that mentioned setting the switch override to true, so I thought that it might be bad to expect to get specific behavior by setting its override switch to false. The documentation proves my assumption wrong: `If your app runs on .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions, but targets an earlier version, the switch defaults to true`. So, I'll probably just set Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions to false and let the OS handle the security.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon Mourier was correct, setting `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto=false" />` in the config file is the official way to add `Tls12` as a default protocol.